# How do we use can in questions

Tags: modal-verbs

One person here explained me the difference between can and could

"**Could** indicates that something is possible, but not certain. **Can** is used in general statements about what is possible.

So, you may use 'can' to speak about the weather in general, such as "it can rain a lot in winter*" or "it can be very dry during the summer". However, your example is about a specific forecast - tomorrow - so it isn't a generalisation."

I still have one issue related to questions my book says that this example is fine "who can be knocking on the door?". Why is it correct. It's not a generalisation plus it's not about abilties but rather likelihood?

Comment: Yes, another use of **can** is to wonder about who/what an unidentified person or thing is. "Who can that be, knocking on the door at this time of night?" "This is a mysterious parcel. What can it be?"

Comment: Are we allowed to use "may" in that question?

Comment: You are not forbidden to (!) but it wouldn't sound natural.

Comment: You can also say "who could it be knocking on the door?"

Comment: It absolutely **is** a question about likelihood, or possibility. "*Who could be knocking at the door*" is the idiomatic choice.

Comment: Usage changes. We *used* to favour [*Who **can** that be?*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Who+could+that+be%2CWho+can+that+be&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), but *Who **could** that be?* has become far more likely in recent decades.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think we *favour* a modal... we use the most appropriate one. Beware misleading ngram results! For example, your data contains a 2017 published work, but the author died in 1940.

Comment: @Astralbee: There are probably at least several hundred written instances either side of the "crossover" point around 1980, so 1 misdated entry is insignificant. Or are you implying that NGram charts are too inaccurate to *ever* reflect usage changes over time? That seems a bit extreme.